# Neutrino interaction probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, neutrinos, interactions

Just a quick question, if a single 1GeV neutrino (muon neutrino) were fired at a block of iron with a  given density, $\rho$, and the neutrino-nucleon interaction cross section is $\sigma$, what would the probability be that the neutrino interacts with an Iron nucleus?

This is a condensed version of Q.3.6 from Thomson, M "Modern Particle Physics", an excellent book.

I'd like to know how to calculate this as I want to play around with the probability for different densities and materials, etc.

Comment: You should post work to show what you've attempted to give us context and to show what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Zach466920 This sounds really bad, but I don't even know where to start!

Comment: Can you convert *ρ* into a nucleon density (nucleons per unit volume)? Think of the neutrino sweeping a cylinder of volume *σz* through the material, where *z* is the thickness of the block. What is *ρσz* then? Have you read up on [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics))?

Comment: I all seriousness the *best* place to start is far enough back that this becomes obvious. But even if you aren't going to do that go back and think hard about the meaning of interaction cross-sections and work from there.

Comment: If you keep having trouble with the book, here is the Instructor's manual. But remember you should try to work out the problems yourself first ;)
https://www.scribd.com/document/349210523/ModernParticlePhysics-InstructorsManual-pdf